# Mac OS X Server: Snow or not?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, osx-leopard

So I'm working for this small company that has 4-5 macs and 3-4 iphones they want to connect together (calendards, contacts, mail, etc). They already have a mini with 10.5.5 Server on it, but I'm about to format and reinstall everything (they're not using the server yet so it won't be a problem).

Does any of you have experience with Snow Leopard Server? Is it buggy? Does it have limitations compared to 10.5? Will it blend in a network of Leopard 10.5 macs?

Comment: With 4-5 macs and snow leopard client upgrades $39.99 a pop, it may be the best bet to bring everyone up to date, if possible.

Comment: Had very bad experiences on SL clients. IMO it's still pretty buggy. Thought maybe it was different with SL Server.

Comment: You should try again SL after the release of upgrades. They deliver a bunch of fixes that may solve your problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm in the middle of planning and deploying a Snow Leopard environment. After some extensive testing I can tell you that yes your SL server will not play nicely with Leopard clients. From the Address Book Server Admin Guide

`The only versions of the Address Book application that support using Address Book Server are those in Mac OS X version 10.6. Earlier versions of Address Book don’t support binding to Address Book Server.`

Calendaring and mail should not be a problem to the Leopard clients as well as the iPhones. Unless you plan on upgrading all your clients I would stick with 10.5 Server and install something like Kerio Mail Server for contact/calendar sync.

Comment: Doesn't 10.5 have contact/calendar syncing built in? Why would I need Kerio Mail Server?

Comment: AFAIK, no 10.5 server does not have contact sync. It has OpenLDAP but that's not the same thing. Kerio is a mail server collaboration suite that emulates Microsoft Exchange. Works quite nicely for mail/contact/calendaring.

Comment: Snow Leopard Server plays great with Leopard clients - only the Address Book Server feature requires the clients to have 10.6 just as Leopard Server required 10.5 clients for iCal Server.