# Microsoft Exchange for Mac

Tags: osx-leopard

So I need to setup 4 macs and 4 iphones with a Mac Mini with Leopard Server that will do contact and calendar syncing with all the devices, inside or outside the network. Apparently OS X Server doesn't do that (refering to syntaxcollector's answer to my previous question: [Mac OS X Server: Snow or not?](https://serverfault.com/questions/76975/mac-os-x-server-snow-or-not))

He recommended me Kerio MailServer to do contact and calendar syncing. 599$. What am I not getting here? What is the purpose of Leopard Server if it doesn't do this? What do you use to do contact/calendar syncing?

Comment: Can you clarify "What is the purpose of Leopard Server if it doesn't do this" please? Do you mean "why do I need Kerio AND 10.5 Server instead of Kerio installed on 10.5 Client" or do you mean "what other features does 10.5 Server have besides calendering" or? Fwiw, Snow Leopard server has a new AddressBook server and its iCal service works better now with clients that aren't bound

Comment: I meant "why do I need Kerio AND 10.5 Server instead of Kerio installed on 10.5 Client". Would love to have an answer to that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful with your terminology:

Leopard Server (10.5) does not support Contact Sync (Address Book Server), neither do Leopard Clients (10.5).

Only Snow Leopard Clients (10.6) and Snow Leopard Server (10.6) support Contact Sync out-of-the-box.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. So if I don't want to upgrade the clients to 10.6, but want to have contact/calendar syncing, what do you recommend I should use? Thanks.

Comment: @Sam V: Calendar syncing works with 10.5, I'm afraid I don't have any recommendations for contact sync. I don't know your reasons for not wanting to upgrade clients, but bear in mind Snow Leopard (10.6) Server unlimited client licence (more than 10 users) is only $499, and $29 per client. Can really not upgrade to Snow Leopard?

Comment: I'm having a bad personal experience with SL client. Never regretted so much of doing an OS upgrade in 10 years of using Macs.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use this for calendar syncing:
http://trac.calendarserver.org/

If you don't want to pay a lot and not host it, gmail does a great job for syncing everything (calendar, contacts ect).

Comment: Google Calendar works fine, however contact syncing is extremely frustrating especially with Address Book. In my experience, contacts sync fine between server and iPhone, but not with Address Book.